# W3C and/or accepted standards for loading non-visual web page resources

Tags: javascript, html, css, w3c, w3c-validation

A few years ago I was employed to develop web front-ends for client applications to W3C/AA compliant standards. I was told that CSS, JS and other non-visual/non-presentational content should **ALWAYS** be kept in the head tag.

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="site.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Code here...
        });
    </script>
<head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This approach has always worked for me, but In my current role I've been asked to move the CSS and JS references all to the bottom of the document for performance/execution reasons

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
<head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        ...
    </div>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="site.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Code here...
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was told that doing this didn't break any compliance or acceptability standards and allowed the site to load faster in some cases, however this caused more problems than it fixed.

Therefore I would like to know if I should stick by my decision to keep these resources in the head tag, or, on the other hand if there is any compelling argument for having resource tags at the bottom, or scattered about the document?

Comment: What kind of problems did the second example caused? I usually put the `scripts` on bottom like the second example. And the `stylesheets` on the `header`. Though, I don't know what the best practices are.

Comment: @azhpo, moving the script files to the bottom caused ALL of the functionality on the page to break. My understanding of jQuery's .ready() function was to allow the scripts to execute only once the DOM had completely loaded, thus allowing scripts to remain in the head. As for CSS styles, SVG elements glitch horribly when CSS is applied to the end of the document.

Comment: "any compliance or acceptability standards": Does this include or exclude formal/syntactical HTML5 rules (i.e., does it matter if the document would be invalid)?

Comment: @unor include formal/syntactical HTML5 rules...I guess :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`link`** elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) can’t appear in the `body` element ([unless they are used for Microdata or RDFa](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633)). So your `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" />` has to be a child of the `head` element.

[**`script`** elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can appear in the `body`. It depends on the script and your document if it makes sense to place the `script` element as last child of the `body`. See, for example, the questions

- [JavaScript on the bottom of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11786915/1591669), and
- ["JavaScript placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster" TRUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14547062/1591669) (which is a duplicate, but contains other answers).

If the `script` element has a `src` attribute (i.e., the script is imported from an external file), you could use the `async` and `defer` attributes to control its execution:

- `async`:

  > the script will be executed asynchronously, as soon as it is available
- `defer`:

  > the script is executed when the page has finished parsing
- default (i.e., neither `async` nor `defer`):

  > the script is fetched and executed immediately, before the user agent continues parsing the page
- `async` + `defer`:

  > cause legacy Web browsers that only support `defer` (and not `async`) to fall back to the `defer` behavior instead of the synchronous blocking behavior that is the default

Comment: Apparently although contrary to the current spec, browsers handle link elements as a child of body just fine. See [this recent discussion on the whatwg mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2014Oct/0265.html).

Comment: @steveax - Sure, but browsers handle tons of invalid stuff just fine. The advice not to do it is sound (see Simon Pieters's comments on that thread) so going against that advice is a slippery slope.

Comment: Yes, I agree that if you're going to release code the doesn't follow the spec you need to be very careful, but thought the thread was relevant to the discussion given many of the browser implementers were involved.