# Modal onload in page Bootstrap 3

Tags: events, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, onload

I would like to know how do I make modal automatic when the index page is triggered?

I would like to open one modal index came on the screen, what should I change in bootstrap 3 to come this effect?

Modal in onload window in open page.

Thanks for the help guys.

I put in the following way

I'm doing something wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '#teste' ).modal( 'toggle' );
});
</script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade in" id="teste" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: try to add some code or detailed view of quesion

Answer (score 3):

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '#myModal' ).modal( 'toggle' );
});
```

Is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: This function is for him to appear as Poup-up?

Comment: This function is to open the modal window (if it is closed), when the document is loaded

Comment: this function is to open modal as a poup-up?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm doing something wrong? pair does not work?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#teste').modal({
      show: true,
    })
  });
</script>
```

Example:

```
 <!-- css -->
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myModal').modal({
    show: true,
   })
 });
</script>

 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   Launch demo modal
 </button>

 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-     labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         ...
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
       </div>
     </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: oi junior Valew pela ajuda, inclui o codigo e nada acontece, esta como o codigo acima só troquei pelo que vc passou, eu inseri o javascript na head, sera que falta algo para funcionar?

Comment: @barbaraEster bem, o código esta certo, se não funciono pode ser algum erro no javascript do bootstrap, ou você não incluiu corretamente. O modal funciona normalmente se você o chamar via button?

Comment: Então pode ser algum erro na inclusão javascript. Tente ver o console do navegador, se ele imprime algum erro. Recomendo criar uma página em branco, incluir o bootstrap do zero, retirar qualquer javascript avulso e tentar abrir o modal. Javascript é meio chato para conflito, eu não mexo muito bem, mas as vezes da conflito se você tiver usando um outro js para outra função.

Comment: Blz Junior ja montei tudo de nv peguei desdo zero, vou fazer o teste aqui agora, só pra ter certeza antes de incluir o modal posso pegar o do via button mesmo? que seria essa parte?

Comment: Desculpa, mas não entendi.

Comment: que seria o padrão para xamar o modal sem o button.

Comment: dai só tiro a chamada button e incluo <!--modal -->... e insero o javascript no head certo?

Comment: @barbaraEster veja o exemplo que postei.

Comment: to usando o console de erro firefox no JS ele aponta pra erros:

Comment: esse tbm da mas é do html:[11:39:18.327] A codificação de caracteres do documento HTML não foi declarada. O documento será exibido com texto corrompido em algumas configurações de navegadores se o documento contiver caracteres fora da faixa US-ASCII. A codificação de caracteres da página deve ser declarada no documento ou protocolo de transferência. @ http://localhost/teste/

Comment: esse do jquery:[11:39:18.333] O método getPreventDefault() não deve mais ser usado. No lugar, use defaultPrevented. @ https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js:5375

Comment: e esse tbm:[11:39:17.992] Os métodos getUserData() ou setUserData() não devem mais ser usados. No lugar, use WeakMap ou element.dataset. @ resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> file:///C:/Users/usuario/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/g41q0g0q.default/extensions/searchads@instair.net/bootstrap.js -> file:///C:/Users/usuario/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/g41q0g0q.default/extensions/searchads@instair.net/lib/requestNotifier.js:47

Comment: Como já disse, faça uma página em branco, inclua o bootstrap css, bootstrap js e jquery. E faça chamada, igual exemplo que te passei em cima, vai funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will actually work. The thing you are doing wrong is the placement of the javascript portion.

You simply need to put the javascript portion of your code at the bottom of your document just before the closing body tag.

I just tested your code, as is, with a long document and it fails. All I did was move your javascript to the bottom of the page and it works perfectly.

There is another stack overflow that talks about why this is a best practice in some cases ([JavaScript on the bottom of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786915/javascript-on-the-bottom-of-the-page)).

Best to you!