# Code is working in jsfiddle but not in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code works in fiddle but not in the html file:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#savebtn").click(function() {
    var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
    localStorage.setItem(title, editElem.value);
    titles = localStorage.getItem("titles");

    if (titles == null) {
      titles = [];
    } else {
      titles = JSON.parse(titles);
    }
    titles.push(title);
    localStorage.setItem("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";
    var htmlData = "<a onclick=showData('" + title + "')>" + title + "</a><br>";
    $("#Contentable").append(htmlData);
    var userVersion = editElem.value;
    localStorage.setItem("userEdits", userVersion);
    editElem.value = "";
  });
});

function showData(txt) {
  editElem.value = localStorage.getItem(txt);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='text' id="editor1" />
<input type='button' id="savebtn" value="save" />
<div id="Contentable"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="update"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4uwvcrdc/
I've checked the console in chrome; there are no errors. I also moved the script to below my body, it still doesn't work.

Comment: move `editElem = document.getElementById("editor1")` to document ready handler or move the entire code at the end of html ........ most of the snippet the script would be after the code or in a document ready handler....... in your code you can't get `editor1` before loading the element

Comment: [javascript-on-the-bottom-of-the-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786915/javascript-on-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small correction with linking external **js** file. Change

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
</script>

<script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#savebtn").click(function() {
        var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
        localStorage.setItem(title, editElem.value);
        titles = localStorage.getItem("titles");

        if (titles == null) {
          titles = [];
        } else {
          titles = JSON.parse(titles);
        }
        titles.push(title);
        localStorage.setItem("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));
        document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";
        var htmlData = "<a onclick=showData('" + title + "')>" + title + "</a><br>";
        $("#Contentable").append(htmlData);
        var userVersion = editElem.value;
        localStorage.setItem("userEdits", userVersion);
        editElem.value = "";
      });
    });

    function showData(txt) {
      editElem.value = localStorage.getItem(txt);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type='text' id="editor1" />
  <input type='button' id="savebtn" value="save" />
  <div id="Contentable"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="update"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this line of code before `document.ready`:

```
var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
```

When that runs the item with the `id` of `"editor1"` has not loaded yet since the JS is ran at the top of the HTML file in the `<head>`. In jsFiddle it will run the JavaScript on a `window.load` event by default. Place that inside your `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
    ...
```

Comment: eiditItem should be in global scope other wise you can't access it inside `showData`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Didn't notice they used it in their function, fixed. Or they could define the function `showData` inside `document.ready`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek :  I think it would be much better to use `on()` method instead of inline `onclick`.... event delegation.... add it in your answer.......

Comment: @PranavCBalan It's just a single static `input` element, I don't see why it's entirely necessary in this case. There aren't any descendant elements to take advantage of event delegation.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek they are not static `$("#Contentable").append(htmlData);`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Sure, thought you meant the `#savebtn`.

Answer (score 0):

It can not read Jquery library. so you need to change your code

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"> </script>
<script>your javascript code  </script>
```

Then, you can use Jquery library and your click event works!