# Sticky Div within Container - no overlap with footer

Tags: css, sticky

I am using this jsfiddle:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVzmz/1/)

In my site, I am getting the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

The line where it breaks of the jsfiddle:

```
var sidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top;
```

What could be the reason?

---

Just to give an idea of what I am trying to solve. I have a div in top of page, and set its position to fixed. When user scroll to the bottom of page, this div overlaps with the footer. I need to to stop (stick) this div in some place and does not go more to the bottom once it passes some point

Comment: when it's breaking ?

Comment: it breaks on page load

Comment: Just to give an idea of what I am trying to solve. I have a div in top of page, and set its position to fixed. When user scroll to the bottom of page, this div overlaps with the footer. I need to to stop (stick) this div in some place and does not go more to the bottom once it passes some point.

Answer (score 0):

It's not breaking on either your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SVzmz/1/) or on my side. There might be possibility that you write your js script before the html is loaded. so try to write the js/jquery code at the end after your html page.

**Refferences** [JavaScript on the bottom of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786915/javascript-on-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: Thanks Nalin. For some reason, I am not getting the error but code is not doing what it is supposed to do. The div does not get sticky.

Comment: the red div should be sticky ? @user2954449

Comment: The yerllow div should be sticky. And should not overlap the footer.

Comment: It's working fine.it's not overlapping. I added upto 12 textboxces, stil no effect with scrolling on minimum screen or larger. @user2954449

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.